# Plot means of different columns, separated by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean

I'm new to this forum and a total beginner in R. I'm using R for the statistical analysis in my masters project, and specifically I struggle to plot means for different columns.

Context: I measured soil fauna activity at different plots (distributed across 8 plot sites). For that, I inserted sticks with holes (16 holes per stick) filled with a powder, and then checked the consumption of the powder in each hole. I inserted the consumption value as decimal fraction (6 categorical values from 0 to 1) and made a column for each hole number (thus 16 columns with consumption values). Now I would like to:

- plot the average consumption per stick (i.e. mean of all 16 holes together) by site
- plot the average consumption of each individual holes (i.e. 16 means) by site

I have used melt() to restructure my data from wide to long format, and I have tried different ways to plot means using ggplot(). However, none of them worked/I got error messages and could not figure out a solution. So I thought maybe somebody here could help me.

```
bait_means_plot <- ggplot(baits.long, aes(x=hole, y=consumption, fill=site))
```

bait_means_plot + stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", position ="dodge", width = 0.9)  +
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_normal, geom = "errorbar", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.3)

Above example for instance did just plot the categorical values instead of the means, while the same code worked for another data set. Is there a simple fix/work-around, or would I rather need another approach?

Below two screenshots that hopefully help explaining my data strucutre (in wide & then in long format). If there is any way by which I could easily provide the original data file and/or R script, I'd happily do so (just did not see such an option writing the question).

[wide data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywkwf.jpg)
[long data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWfGq.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Posting data as images is not a good idea for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).   Far better is to edit your question to include the output from `dput(<yourdata>)`, where `<yourdata>` is (a subset of) your input data.

Comment: @Limey thanks for the notice, I wasn't aware of that. I will pay attention to that in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had to figure out similar things myself in the past few months, this is what worked for me and I hope it's useful. It is dependent on having the tidyverse loaded so make sure you have that

To group them in ggplot, use the long data and add "group =" to your aes section, you can also colour code them by adding "colour =" to the aes call e.g.

```
aes(x=hole, y=consumption, group=site, colour =site))
```

If you use group_by() then tidyverse functions will operate on each group (unique entry in that column) separately, so you'd use the long data format. This can be useful for summary statistics, especially the summarise () function The %>% used in the code is the pipe operator, which inserts what came before it as the first argument in the function.

```
long_data %>% group_by(site)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I did not notice that I used the aesthetics arguments incorrectly/incompletely, your input made it work :)